# Very complicated limit and trying to find convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

I have no idea how to prove this:

> $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^2 \times4^2\times6^2\times\dots\times(2n)^2}{(1\times3)(3\times5)\dots((2n-1)(2n+1))} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^2 \times4^2\times6^2\times\dots\times(2n)^2}{1^2 \times3^2\times5^2\times\dots\times(2n-1)^2}\frac{1}{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\pi$

I know I need to use the squeeze theorem in some way, but this just feels so overwhelming!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the inequalities $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}tdt\leqslant \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n}tdt\leqslant \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-1}tdt$$ and massage that.

*Spoiler* Let $x_m=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{m}tdt$. Then $${x_{m + 2}} = \int\limits_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin }^m}t{{\sin }^2}tdt}  = \int\limits_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin }^m}t\left( {1 - {{\cos }^2}t} \right)dt}  = {x_m} - \int\limits_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin }^m}t\cos t\cos tdt} $$

But $(\sin^{m+1}t)'=(m+1)\sin^m t\cos t$, so integrating by parts $$\int\limits_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin }^m}t\cos t\cos tdt}  =  - \frac{1}{{m + 1}}\int\limits_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin }^{m + 1}}t\sin tdt}  =  - \frac{1}{{m + 1}}\int\limits_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin }^{m + 2}}tdt} $$

and $x_{m+2}=x_m+\dfrac{1}{m+1}x_{m+2}$, which gives $x_{m+2}=\dfrac{m+1}mx_m$. According to whether $m$ is even or odd, $\pi/2$ will or will not appear. Note also that $x_{m+2}/x_m\to 1$.

Comment: How do I related what I have as my limit to $\sin (t)$?

Comment: @InsigMath: Try integration by parts.

Comment: I wouldn't come up with such a beautiful answer in a thousand year of studies. Chapeau, good sir.

Comment: I know how to do integration by parts, I am just not seeing why you are using $sin(t)$ in the first place, for instance $\int sin^2 = \pi/4$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$

Comment: Hmm .. it does get closer to our result, is that what you are getting at?

Comment: @InsigMath Think 'recursive formulas'.